# Javascript form validation, what is missing?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I can't get a form to validate no matter what I try, so I have dumbed it down alot to see if I could get ANYTHING to work, and still when I submit the form the javascript does not validate, and simply sends me to the next page no matter what. You guys see anything wrong??

HTML

```
<form id="myform" action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate()">
<input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
<div id="error">Name too short</div>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Enter" />
```

JAVASCRIPT IN HEAD

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   function Validate() {
      if (form.name.value == "") {
         $('#error').show();
         return false ;
       }
      return true ;
   }
</script>
```

And in the CSS I have the display for the #error div set to none. 
Ultimately I want to check that the user entered at least 4 characters in the text input field, if they didnt then I don't want the form submitted but rather show the error message. But for now I'm just checking to see if its empty to see if I can get anything to work. Any ideas?

Comment: hi dude value of form.name.value might  be **undefined** also you have to check too

Comment: Is form.name defined?

Comment: Ok do you mind giving me an example of how to Define it? I come here asking because I'm at a loss. I'm a javascript newbie and all my searching in google isn't pulling any solutions... Actually I have been finind tons of solutions, but nothing works so far.

Comment: You are using `form.name` but the id of your input is `form_name`.

Comment: Ok I made those changes, still not working.

Comment: @RandyC Have you included jquery ? If you remove the line `$('#error').show();`, does it work ?

Comment: No removing that line still doesnt work. And I tested this bare code I have posted here like others have, they said it works, and its still not working. Javascript is working fine every where else as far as I can tell too

Comment: What browser are you using for your test ?

Comment: Firefox, testing on chrome and IE also... :( what sucks is I have written some similar working code on this computer recently too. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove `language` from the script tag, it's deprecated. 
Then you should not load your script in the `head` section. Instead put it where `body` ends to ensure that the HTML has loaded.

Also in your validate function you don't seem to actually target the correct ID's.

Use this:

```
function Validate() {
  if ($('#form_name').val() === '') {
    $('#error').show();
    return false ;
  }
   return true ;
}
```

Comment: Use `val()` instead of just `val`.

Comment: Ok I tried all these changes, still it submits and sends to the next page, nopt solved yet. Thanks for your help, but any other ideas? How can this not work lol

Comment: @RandyC Why are you submitting to "/"? Is that a real page even?

Comment: It works for me with the given html of the OP and this javascript.

Comment: Thats just for an example, I have it submitting to a seperate page.

Comment: @RandyC Could you post more of your code? Include the non dumbed version because that's probably where the culprit is.

Answer (score 0):

Define IDs for tags and use jQuery to get those tags and check their values. For example, if the name tag had id="form_name" you could do something like this:

```
if ($("#form_name").val() == ""))
    $('#error').show();
```

On the other hand, I recommend you to check jQuery Validate plug-in which is great for validating forms:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

Replace your javascript for this

```
function Validate() {
    // Use form_name instead of form.name
    if (form_name.value == "") {
      // This line will break if you do not have jquery.
      $('#error').show();
    return false ;
  }
  return true ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (form.name.value == "") {
```

use:

```
var nameField=document.getElementById("form_name");
if (nameField.value == "") {
```

Let me know if this works.